# find files or directories that are 30 or more days old, recursively, BUT starting the search from specific directory

Tags: linux, find

I have been searching but I cannot find a way to essentially do the following in 1 line at Linux, so as to find files and directories that are more than 30 days old, starting the recursive search from script_dir:

```
cd $script_dir
find . -type f -or -type d -mtime +30
```

If I do not do the cd to change to directory that I need to start searching from recursively (and use directly only the find), then, although I specify the script_dir at find the recursive search starts from the directory I am currently and NOT from the script_dir and beneath this directory. I want to do something like the following and even if I am currently at other directory than script_dir, the recursive search to start from script_dir:

```
find $script_dir -type f -or -type d -mtime +30
```

Thank you.

Comment: doesn't `find "$script_dir" -type f -or -type d -mtime +30` do what you want? It should. Good luck.

Comment: No, it does not.  It works the same as  find . -type f -or -type d -mtime +30, at the directory you are currently at, thus ignoring the $script_dir.

Comment: doah, I think we need to protect the `-or` like `find "$script_dir" \( -type f -or -type d \) -mtime +30`  (The escaped `()` pair). predicates in find are joined with an default `-and`, but `-or` needs to be "protected" from premature evaluations . IHTH and Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In one line, you can do like this :

```
cd /path/to/directory && find . -type f -or -type d -mtime +30
```

that do the search from the specified directory